# Price of bottle shown as price of one shot

Tags: magento-1.9, price, special-price

I hope it isn't too bold to ask for help.
I sell bottles of liquor and I want to show under price of bottle (item) converted price of one shot.

My idea is this

> If attribute '*show_shot_price*' says '*Yes*', then it should find out
>   what price is current whether *price* or *special_price*.
>
> Then I have several options with *volume*.
>
> If attribute *volume* has options **1 liter** it should divide the
>   price by 25 (40 milliliter shot).
>
> **0,7 liter** price/17,5.
>
> **0,5 liter** price/12,5.

And the result should be round to whole number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');
$shotPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice() / ($volume * 25);
$displayShotPrice = $coreHelper->formatPrice($shotPrice);
```

now you just have to print `$displayShotPrice`

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Oh, Marius :D

Comment: @fschmengler. Well...the SE bots are wrong on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody need the same as me here is my final code where I work with weight attribute as volume.

```
<?php if($_product->getData('attribute_show_shot_price')==1): ?>
                <?php $coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

                $weight=$_product->getweight(); 

                $shotPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice() * 40 / $weight;
                $displayShotPrice = $coreHelper->formatPrice($shotPrice); ?>

                <?php echo $displayShotPrice ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```